# MySQL 'duplicate entry' error

Tags: mysql, wpdb

Why am I getting an error, and how do I fix it?

This is how I create a table:

```
$wpdb->query("
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$wpdb->prefix}tdlrm_references`(
        ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
        ref_type varchar(100),
        ref_id varchar(100),
        ref_name varchar(1024),
        data_type varchar(40),
        related_to varchar(40),       
        PRIMARY KEY  (ID),
        UNIQUE KEY `reference` (`ref_type`,`ref_id`)                                           
    )");
```

these are the rows I have:

```
| ID  | ref_type    | ref_id      | ref_name    | data_type | related_to  |
|-----|-------------|-------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|
| 100 | property_1C | (16digits1) | (something) | checkbox  | (something) |
| 101 | property_1C | (16digits2) | (something) | checkbox  | (something) |
```

Somewhere else, I've got this command:

```
$wpdb->query("
  UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}tdlrm_references
  SET ref_type = 'property_1C_multiple', ref_id=ref_id
  WHERE data_type = 'checkbox'
");
```

`$wpdb->show_errors();` prints this error:

```
[Duplicate entry 'property_1C_multiple-b9ff7e34-35f8-11eb-aa57-94de80b27027'
for key 'reference']
<code>UPDATE wp_tdlrm_references
SET ref_type = 'property_1C_multiple', ref_id=ref_id
WHERE data_type = 'checkbox'</code>
```

When I comment out this line, the problem goes away.

Why? Raw SQL in PHPMyAdmin gives me no errors. The `ref_id` cell is different in both rows, so the combined `reference (ref_type+ref_id)` key should not get duplicated.

**Update:**

I get the error when I run both queries at once:

```
INSERT INTO wp_tdlrm_references (
            ref_type,
            ref_id,
            ref_name,
            data_type,
            related_to
       )
        SELECT
           'property_1C',
            Id,
            Name,
            ValueType,
            related_to
        FROM wp_tdlrm_temp_properties
        WHERE Id != '//import'
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ref_name = Name, wp_tdlrm_references.related_to = wp_tdlrm_temp_properties.related_to;
        
UPDATE wp_tdlrm_references SET ref_type = 'property_1C_multiple' WHERE data_type = 'checkbox';
```

Comment: Do you really want to set ref_id to ref_id? Shouldn’t you pass some value in there to your query?

Comment: Hello Krzysiek Dróżdż. It's there because I'm trying to figure out why the composite key is duplicated. `ref_id` already has some value in each row, that's why I pass no value, I haven't had `ref_id=ref_id` before I started troubleshooting.

Comment: The "duplicate entry" error could happen if you've got an existing row where `ref_type` is `property_1C_multiple` and `ref_id` is `b9ff7e34-35f8-11eb-aa57-94de80b27027`, and another row with the same `ref_id`, but with `property_1C` being the `ref_type`. Because when MySQL attempts to update the another row, the key then gets duplicated.

Comment: Sally CJ hello ) No, there is no such row. There is one where `ref_id` is `b9ff7e34-35f8-11eb-aa57-94de80b27027` (same id), `ref_type` is `'property_site'` and `data_type` is `'on'`. It should not cause an error, since `ref_id` does not have to be unique, only `ref_type+ref_id`

Comment: There must be something going on under the hood that I don't understand, since my MySQL query is OK. Maybe I have to revise the whole piece of code. Hey, do you think I can do the task in some other way? I need to change `ref_type` to `'property_1C_multiple'` where `data_type` is `'checkbox'` in one $wpdb query.

Comment: You could try updating by ID instead, something like `UPDATE wp_tdlrm_references SET ref_type = 'property_1C_multiple' WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3)`, but you'd still get the same error if any of the new references are already in the existing references list. So I'd try `SELECT ID, ref_type, ref_id, data_type, CONCAT('property_1C_multiple', ref_id) ref FROM wp_tdlrm_references;` (in phpMyAdmin) and see if there are any *duplicate `ref`* entries in the results?

Comment: If none, then you could try the common troubleshooting steps like deactivating plugins and clearing caches. Also, where/when/how are you calling the function/file where you run `$wpdb->query()`? Are you doing that in admin or the front-end, and what hook did you use, if any?

Comment: Nothing you suggested gives me duplicate keys. Also, if I run my query from PHPMyAdmin, it works just fine. As for the function, I've written a plugin. A third-party program sends it http requests with commands and files. XML files get parsed into temporary tables, then my plugin gets a command to start importing, the temp data gets converted into wp posts, terms etc. So, the plugin just gets an http request, plugin file calls the function, the function contains 2 wpdb queries... Wait a second. Are wpdb queries asynchronous?

Comment: "Are wpdb queries asynchronous?" - the next query will only be executed after the previous one is complete. So, "2 wpdb queries" - are they INSERT and UPDATE? Try `var_dump()`-ing the queries and see if they are good (try running or reproducing the commands in phpMyAdmin).

Comment: Yes, they are INSERT (values selected from temp table) and UPDATE. Tomorrow I'll comment the first one out and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, so I've commented out the first query, and there's no error now. I get the error only when I run both. See thу update to my question.

Comment: Perhaps the issue was as I said in my very first comment, otherwise MySQL wouldn't give you such error. So how about running the queries one-by-one.. first, select the data from the temp table, then insert them into the main table - and when you insert, just set the `ref_type` to `property_1C_multiple` if the `data_type` is `checkbox`. Or you could use `UPDATE IGNORE` instead of just `UPDATE` (i.e. use the `IGNORE` modifier), but that's really a MySQL thing.. so check the MySQL [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) for more details.